# How can I compile scanbd on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: compiling, scanner

I am trying to get the buttons on my **Canon CanoScan LiDE 60** to work. So far I installed the `sane-utils`, the printer is detected and I can scan. However the front buttons on the scanner are not detected by SANE. I read in this case, one should compile `scandb` from sources and run `./configure --enable-scanbuttond` which I did and then run make. However `make` doesn't complete, as there is a warning which is treated as an error:

```
config.c: In function ‘cfg_do_parse’:
config.c:117:5: error: ‘strncpy’ specified bound 4096 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
     strncpy(config_file, config_file_name, PATH_MAX);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [Makefile:503: config.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/scanbd-1.5.1/src/scanbd'
make: *** [Makefile:425: all-recursive] Error 1
```

Is there either a simpler way to get the buttons working or how can I compile scanbd to get my buttons to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning that's being treated as an error By the C compiler is causing the compilation to fail.

You can have it treated as a warning by compiling with the following:

```
make CFLAGS="-Wno-error=stringop-truncation"
```

If you receive errors where it's the CXX compiler:

```
make CXXLAGS="-Wno-error=format-truncation"
```

Comment: Thanks Nasir, worked right away, however I don't get why the released source in 1.5.1 has this flaw.